# Scroll screen in IOS

Tags: ios, scroll, background

I have been trying to find a way to use a background image so that it is larger than the device screen size, IE: the user can scroll from top to bottom and side to side to view the entire image.

This is something I'm looking at in gaming.  I just haven't found any way to do this, I know its because I'm looking in the wrong place or asking the question in an incorrect manner, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Easy and straight forward answer....I never figured that out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem you can use scrollView and insert in it a content view , and give it say 3 times widths/heights of screen , see demo here [ScrollAnyway](https://github.com/ShKhan9/scrollAnyway)